# Call a pagination block in Category page

Tags: magento-1.7, blocks, category, toolbar, pagination

In the product display page(i.e., category page in catalog/product/list.phtml of grid view), before and after the product items Toolbar block is being displayed(with this `<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>` ), my requirement is to display only Pagination block(i hope it is a separate block) after the product items.

so i replaced `<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>` with `<?php echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_toolbar')->getPagerHtml() ?>`.

Can some one help me how can i display only pagination block after the products list?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Hello call your create custom toolbar.phtml & call into grid view

1.Comment `$this->getToolbarHtml()` & add below code

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarBlock()->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/newtoolbar.phtml')->toHtml() ?>
```

2.Copy content from toolbar.phtml to newtoolbar.phtml (change as your requirement)

```
app/design/frontend/(base or default)/(default or your
theme)/template/catalog/product/list/newtoolbar.phtml
```